# How to put mathematical equations in source code without making it unreadable?

Tags: math, syntax, rust

When implementing complex calculations, I found that readability suffered a lot. For example, this formula is absolutely unreadable when translated to code (I chose Rust since the strong typing makes it even worse):

[image]

```rust
let s2 = (2.0 * (s as f64) * ((180.0 - a) / 2.0).sin()) / a.sin();
```

How do you deal with math in your code? I thought of putting the math in a LaTeX file and converting it to actual code during compilation, is that something which has been done before?

Comment: Typically the way to cope with that is to break the expression into smaller parts. This is also important because computers don't solve those like humans do. Numerical computations are a complex topic, and trying to "abstract" the programming language away will end up in problems sooner or later.

Comment: *I thought of putting the math in a LaTeX file and converting it to actual code during compilation, is that something which has been done before?*. Yes, actually, it has.  Point your favourite search engine at *literate programming*.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the internet  I came across a [Pull Request](https://github.com/rust-num/num/pull/226/files) at the rust-num crate.

You can use the `RUSTDOCFLAGS` environment variable to embed html pages which can contain javascript. In this case [kaTeX](https://katex.org/) is used. (the following is a summary of the PR).

1. Add `--html-in-header doc/header.html --html-after-content doc/after.html` to the `RUSTDOCFLAGS` environment variable
2. Put your formula into your doc comment, e.g. `$s' = \frac{2 \cdot s \cdot \sin \left( \frac{180 - \alpha}{2} \right) }{\sin \left( \alpha \right) } $`
3. Content of doc/after.html:

   ```html
   <script>renderMathInElement(document.body, {
     delimiters: [
       {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
       {left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true},
       {left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false},
       {left: "$", right: "$", display: false}
     ]
   });</script>
   ```
4. Content of doc/header.html

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.6.0/katex.min.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.6.0/katex.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.6.0/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>
   ```

Of course you can alter the links to use a local katex resource instead of a cdn.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asks about translating (formatted) mathematical equations into compilable/compiled code

Comment: @rubenvb while I partially agrre, the title says *"How to put mathematical equations in source code without making it unreadable?"* and using doc comments is one way to go. So I see this as an adequate answer.

Comment: I understand your sentiment, but if the straightforward linearized format as shown by the OP is already unreadable, I doubt adding a layer of obscure markup which takes it even further from the mathematical expression is what is sought.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem, which is not limited to Rust specifically, is to store all calculations (except calculations that are iterative, GPU-specific or otherwise specialized) in Microsoft Excel and to then (re)generate code from Excel whenever I need it.